# How can I add condition in class on the vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component, you can see below :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="panel-group" v-for="item in list">
            ...
            <div :class="'alert ' + item.created_at ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-warning'">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            list: function() {
                return this.$store.state.transaction.list
            },
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

When executed, it display `alert-success`. Whereas `item.created_at = NULL`

Should it display `alert-warning`

If the above conditions are incorrect?

How the correct writing?

Comment: Yeah If condition is not true, in your case it's null, the ternary condition would execute/follow another (else) statement and display `alert-warning`

Comment: @Belmin Bedak, Thanks for your response. Btw, please delete your comment before. Because I had update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `alert` should always be present you could write:

```
<div :class="['alert', item.created_at ? 'alert-success':'alert-warning']">...</div>
```

Don't concatenate in the bindings, use the list notation!